# How to set slidingpanel default state collapse and collapse panel min height?

Tags: android, foursquare, slidingpanelayout

I am using sliding panel foursquare library and as i open the panel activity i found panel to be expanded by default but i wan to set it to be collapse by default so please tell me how to do that?

As i slide down the panel or collapse it  sliding layout get of 40 DP in height but i want it to be of 100 DP minimum.

So please tell me how and where to make changes to have these two things in my app?

what i have tried so far is that changed attributes these field in the sliding panel widget  but none of them is working for me

```
collapseMap();
slidingUpPanelLayout.hidePane()
slidingUpPanelLayout.collapsePane();


app:paralaxOffset="@dimen/paralax_offset"
 app:shadowHeight="0dp"
 app:dragView="@+id/sliding_container"
 app:panelHeight="40dp"
```

Comment: Where did you set the states; inside `onCreate()`? Maybe you can read the wiki at the original SlidingUpPanelLayout from Umano https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: @eee i have resolved my one problem regarding setting sliding panel layout to be collapsed by default but please tell me how to change the height of the collapsed panel

Answer (score 3):

sliding panel foursquare library is actually implementing this library:https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

and i have used this AndroidSlidingUpPanel library and for this I used 
mSlideLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED);

So i hope this code will help you.

Comment: i have resolved this issue thanx for your revert but can you please help me out from my second issue which i regarding collapsed panel height

Comment: I had used like this:
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="@color/hk_white"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="@dimen/Size_100"
        sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp">

Comment: i did but any of these didn't work for me, i have mentioned attributes above on question which i have chaned

Comment: so use sothree instead of app to change pannel height in xml
see my code

Comment: id don't think it will make any difference because i have entered app in xmnls attributie o XML

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default state from the layout xml file itself.
Add the below attributes to the com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout

```
app:umanoInitialState="collapsed"
```

For collapsed panel height

```
app:umanoPanelHeight="100dp"
```